# Management studio is not showing after SQLEXPR_x64_ENU installtion

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQLEXPR_x64_ENU (2014) on Windows 10. Im not able to see the Management Studio. What is the problem?

Comment: Consider downloading the [latest SSMS version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), which is a stand-aline install and backwards compatible with SQL 2014.

Comment: 2014 was the first version of SQL Server to have SSMS as a separate install. Installing SQL Server won't install SSMS.

Comment: I could able to install Management studio. But getting the following error while connecting to the server. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.Im using windows authentication